# Limit of minimizers of a class of functionals

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, sobolev-spaces

Assume that $ \Omega $ is a smooth bounded domain in $ \mathbb{R}^n $. Consider a functional
$$
\mathcal{F}(u)=\int_\Omega(|\nabla u|^2+h^{-1}|u-u_0|^2) \, dx
$$
where $ h>0 $ is a parameter and $ u_0\in H_0^1(\Omega) $. For the minimizing problem
$$ 
\min_{u\in H_0^1(\Omega)}\mathcal{F}(u),
$$
it is easy to get by standard arguments that there is a unique minimizer $ u_h\in H_0^1(\Omega) $, i.e. $ u_h=\operatorname{argmin}_{u\in H_0^1(\Omega)} \mathcal{F}(u) $. A natural observation is that $ \|u_h-u_0\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\to 0 $. I want to ask the following question.

> Let $ h_0>0 $. Assume that $ h\to h_0 $. If there is the result $ \|u_{h}-u_{h_0}\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\to 0 $?

Such question is natural and intuitively true. However I cannot solve it, can you give me some hints or references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By simple calculations, we can obtain that $ u_{h} $ and $ u_{h_0} $ satisfy the following Euler-Lagrange equation
\begin{align}
\frac{u_h-u_0}{h}-\Delta u_{h}=0,\\
\frac{u_{h_0}-u_0}{h}-\Delta u_{h_0}=0.
\end{align}
Then it can be got that
$$
\begin{aligned}
0&=\frac{u_h-u_0}{h}-\frac{u_{h_0}-u_0}{h_0}-\Delta(u_{h}-u_{h_0})\\
&=\frac{u_h-u_0}{h}-\frac{u_h-u_0}{h_0}+\frac{u_h-u_0}{h_0}-\frac{u_{h_0}-u_0}{h_0}-\Delta(u_{h}-u_{h_0})\\
&=(u_h-u_0)\frac{h_0-h}{hh_0}+\frac{u_h-u_{h_0}}{h_0}-\Delta(u_h-u_{h_0}).
\end{aligned}
$$
Testing the above equation by the function $ u_h-u_{h_0} $, we obtain that
$$
\int_{\Omega}|\nabla(u_h-u_{h_0})|^2dx+\int_{\Omega}\frac{(u_{h}-u_{h_0})^2}{h_0}dx\leq\int_{\Omega}\frac{h-h_0}{hh_0}(u_h-u_0)(u_h-u_{h_0})dx.
$$
By Cauchy inequality, we have
$$
\frac{1}{2}\int_{\Omega}(u_h-u_{h_0})^2dx\leq\frac{(h-h_0)^2}{h^2}\int_{\Omega}(u_h-u_0)^2dx.
$$
From this, we can complete the proof.